# Cannot use msn.marginal {sn} in R

Tags: r

I have try many ways, but i still cannot use `msn.marginal` for my research.
When I try to install the package `sn` in the latest R software (Ri386 3.2.0), `msn.marginal` is not in there

```
msn.marginal
```

> Error: object 'msn.marginal' not found

I also tried to install the package of `sn` version 0.4-18, but I still cannot use `msn.marginal`

So, I tried to install the `sn` package of version 0.4-14, but this is what I got

> install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sn/sn_0.4-14.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")
>
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Owner/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sn/sn_0.4-14.tar.gz'
>
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 60084 bytes (58 KB)
>
> downloaded 58 KB
>
> - installing *source* package 'sn' ...
>
> ** R
>
> ** data
>
> ** inst
>
> ** preparing package for lazy loading
>
> ** help
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/dmsn.Rd:12-16:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/dmst.Rd:12-17:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/dsn.Rd:13-18:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/dsn2.plot.Rd:10-12:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/dst.Rd:13-18:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/dst2.plot.Rd:10-12:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/msn.conditional.Rd:12-15:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/msn.marginal.Rd:10-12:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/msn.quantities.Rd:10-12:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/sn.cumulants.Rd:9-11:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> Warning:
>   C:/Users/Owner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpclmZuh/R.INSTALL4ee448bd3fa9/sn/man/st.cumulants.Rd:10-13:
>   Section \synopsis is unrecognized and will be dropped
>
> *** installing help indices
>
> ** building package indices
>
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>
> *** arch - i386
>
> *** arch - x64
>
> - DONE (sn)

```
msn.marginal
```

> Error: object 'msn.marginal' not found

Why `msn.marginal` was dropped?

Comment: yup, i have load the package

Comment: Perhaps it was in the last "version 0", from which they made some significant changes for the current version. If you read the package info for `sn`, it will point you to their website, on which they tell you how to get the previous version. (Don't even need google for it: `packageDescription('sn', field='URL')`.)

Comment: The link that i used to install package is taken from the webside suggested from CRAN

Comment: You don't understand. If it was existent in the previous version, then the package authors *deliberately* changed. CRAN only provides the current version, so you'll need to ask the authors to give you an outdated and unsupported version.

Comment: I think. Unfortunately, I found no changelog, no historical reference to `msn.marginal`, so I'm speculating.

Comment: the old version from here cannot be used?
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sn/index.html

Comment: the reason i will try version  0.4-18 because i found msn.marginal in this link http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sn/docs/msn.marginal

Answer (score 0):

I first removed my copy of the `sn`-package from my library so that I could install from the Archives. Your call to `install.packages` seems to have succeeded (since you got the "DONE"-message), but you appear to have failed either to execute:

```
library(sn)   # since if you had you would either get an error or this message:
Loading required package: mnormt
Package 'sn', 0.4-14 (2010-01-16). Type 'help(SN)' for summary information
```

(If you had executed it, that callshould have either produced an error or that message.) Then this produces code:

```
> msn.marginal
function (xi = rep(0, length(alpha)), Omega, alpha, comp = 1:d, 
    dp = NULL) 
{
    if (!is.null(dp)) {
        if (!is.null(dp$xi)) 
            xi <- dp$xi
        else if (!is.null(dp$beta)) 
            xi <- as.vector(dp$beta)
        Omega <- dp$Omega
        alpha <- dp$alpha
    }
    alpha <- as.vector(alpha)
# Snipped remainder of function code.....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally i can use it